# url change, component doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, render

i have a menu that it contains some items. when i clicked on menu items url changes but component doesn't render and page doesn't change. The strange thing is, when i refresh the url, component will change.

```
const ShoppingList = () => {
  const [forceRender, setForceRender] = useState(false);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9000/productgroup").then((res) => {
      setPosts(res.data);
      console.log().catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <Link to={`/card/${post.id}`} key={post.id}>
            <div className="col-12 listItems" key={post.id}>
              {post.name}
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ShoppingList;
```

item part

```
const ProductItem = () => {
  const itemId = useParams().itemId;
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9000/Products")
      .then((res) => {
        const productData = res.data.filter((x=> x.group === itemId));
        setPosts(productData);
      
        console.log().catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row justify-content-center m-0">
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <ProductItemCard
          photo={post.Pic}
          price={post.price}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

routes part

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/card" element={<Card />} >
    <Route path=":itemId" element={<ProductItem />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

how i can  solve it?

Comment: Where is `ShoppingList` being rendered and what is the `Card` component? Can you share all relevant code? See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "/" in your second route.

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/card" element={<Card />} >
        <Route path=":itemId" element={<ProductItem />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Now the `"/card"` route is missing its closing tag and the JSX is invalid. There is now also no `"/card/:itemId"` route for the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Link to={`/card/${post.id}`} key={post.id}>  - here you navigate to something like '/card/id1' but u didn't create this route. 




         <Routes>
                <Route path="/card" element={<Card />} />
                <Route path="/card/:itemId" element={<ProductItem />}/>
         </Routes>
```

Comment: The `":itemId"` route ***was*** a nested route and defined. Now the `"/card"` route is missing its closing tag and the JSX is invalid.